# How to indent if...any...do...end...end

Tags: ruby, indentation

I am new to ruby and I wonder how you would indent this code:

```
if a.any? do |blah|
name = blah[:name][/.* (.*)/, 1]
name = convert_name(name)
text = "#{name}#{blah[:value]}"
text == "b2"
end
puts "found"
exit 1
end
```

Comment: usually in most languages you indent all lines in a code block, so in this case, i'd wager everything in between your opening `if` and closing `end` should be indented.

Comment: Oh, I just checked and found that [indentation is off topic on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164219/where-should-i-post-about-code-readability). Flagged for migration.

Comment: I added more code to the example to make clear that I am not after a solution to reduce the callback to one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write it something like:

```
if a.any? { |blah| (blah[:name] + blah[:value]) == "b2" }
  puts "found"
  exit 1
end
```

Or:

```
if a.any? { |blah| blah.values_at(:name, :value).join == "b2" }
  puts "found"
  exit 1
end
```

The actual test is short enough that it can be done in a single line.

Generally we use braces (`{}`) for blocks when they return a value or are on a single line.

Interpolating two strings in another string just to join them is smelly. Just concatenate them; It's more obvious what you're doing.

---

If you're *ONLY* concerned about how to indent clearly, consider this:

```
if a.any? do |blah|
    name = blah[:name][/.* (.*)/, 1]
    name = convert_name(name)
    text = "#{name}#{blah[:value]}"
    text == "b2"
  end
  puts "found"
  exit 1
end
```

The `any?` block should be indented further than the contents of the `if` block to visually separate them. Beyond the indention... ugh... the code block for `any?` *should* be refactored to a single line still.

Comment: That is, define a function and use that for `any?`? That would be a solution.

Comment: If you are going to call it in multiple places, then yes, you'd want to define it somewhere and reuse it. If you're only using it one place, then don't artificially "DRY" it. Instead, do it inline.

Comment: So no function. Then when you said it should be refactored to a single line you meant Linuxios' `result` solution.

Answer (score 3):

Like so:

```
if(a.any? { |blah| text = "#{blah[:name]}#{blah[:value]}"; text == "b2"})
  puts "found"
  exit 1
end
```

If your `any?` block is really long, do this:

```
result = a.any? do |blah| 
  text = "#{blah[:name]}#{blah[:value]}"
  text == "b2"
  ...
end
if(result)
  puts "found"
  exit 1
end
```

Comment: Well, there's going to be more in the callback of `any?`, that's why I made it `do` ... `end` in the first place. So just shoving it all into one line is the proper style?

Comment: no, only a trivial comparison should be on a single line. I'd recommend using two because you have two operations. Personally I think that `text` shouldn't be used. Just compare `"b2"` to the value returned by the concatenation of the two values. I'd use `(blah[:name] + blah[:value])` instead of interpolating them into an empty string just to join the two values.

Comment: So you agree with the second solution (using `result`)?

Answer (score 3):

Part of the challenge is to cleanly accommodate both the `if` and `any?` blocks, since both terminate with an `end`. One way to distinguish between them, then, is to use braces for the inner block, to make it clearer what is going on:

```
if a.any? { |blah|
    name = blah[:name][/.* (.*)/, 1]
    name = convert_name(name)
    text = "#{name}#{blah[:value]}"
    text == "b2" }
then
  puts "found"
  exit 1
end
```

Thanks Cary Swoveland for suggesting the `then`.

Comment: This changes the semantics (`text` is gone).

Comment: `text` isn't needed because it's a frivolous assignment; It's only used once, so it got refactored out.

Comment: I see, ruby has block scope. I should have added more code to the example.

Comment: Your question and code in the question should accurately reflect what you're really trying to do. We're going to refactor to what we think is the best solution to fit your example and needs.

Comment: @AndreKR Solution rewritten to reflect your rewrite.

Comment: I like this.  Any reason you chose not to put the closing brace on a line by itself?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Just felt that the indentation was sufficient to visually communicate end-of-block, plus it balances the fact that the opening brace is also not on a line by itself. This is all of course just subjective aesthetics :)

Comment: What about putting the rarely-used `then` after the block, left-adjusted?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good idea! Updated.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably toss the search logic into a lambda:

```
are_wanted = lambda do |blah|
  name = blah[:name][/.* (.*)/, 1]
  name = convert_name(name)
  text = "#{name}#{blah[:value]}"
  text == "b2"
end
```

Then once it has a name so that we can tell what it is for at a glance, the `if` becomes nice and readable:

```
if a.any?(&are_wanted)
  puts "found"
  exit 1
end
```

I find this technique quite useful when you end up with a complicated Enumerable pipeline, things like this for example:

```
pull_em_apart        = lambda { ... }
the_good_ones        = lambda { ... }
put_em_back_together = lambda { ... }
array.map(&pull_em_apart)
     .select(&the_good_ones)
     .map(&put_em_back_together)
```

when the `lambda`s are more than a single line are a lot easier to understand than a big mess of inlined blocks.

Comment: I see the advantage of this approach in your Enumerable pipline example--and have tucked that away--but in this case I don't understand why it would be preferable to just using a variable (e.g., `any_wanted?`), as @Linuxios suggested.

Comment: @Cary: Just a stylistic choice I suppose. I do a fair bit of (Coffee|Java)Script work too so chopping things into a pile of little functions is natural to me.

Comment: There are times when using little functions like this are REALLY useful, especially when you want to have a list of ones to process. That was a Perl thing I used to do all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Another choice:

```
begin
  puts "found"
  exit 1
end if a.any? do |blah|
  name = blah[:name][/.* (.*)/, 1]
  name = convert_name(name)
  text = "#{name}#{blah[:value]}"
  text == "b2"
end
```

Comment: Though valid ruby, this is confusing because the second block is always executed first, then only conditionally is the first block executed after the second. Just my opinion.

Comment: Perhaps, but it is very common to see `do something if something else`.