# Ruby: Link two arrays of objects by attribute value

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, mapping

I'm pretty new in Ruby programming. In Ruby there are plenty ways to write elegant code. Is there any elegant way to link two arrays with objects of the same type by attribute value?

It's hard to explain. Let's look at the next example:

```
a = [ { :id => 1, :value => 1 }, { :id => 2, :value => 2 }, { :id => 3, :value => 3 } ]
b = [ { :id => 1, :value => 2 }, { :id => 3, :value => 4 } ]
c = link a, b

# Result structure after linkage.
c = {
  "1" => {
    :a => { :id => 1, :value => 1 },
    :b => { :id => 1, :value => 1 }
  },
  "3" => {
    :a => { :id => 3, :value => 3 },
    :b => { :id => 3, :value => 4 }
  }
}
```

So the basic idea is to get pairs of objects from different arrays by their common ID and construct a hash, which will give this pair by ID.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also interested to this post's answer. Now tonight my brain is not working to produce an answer for this post. But my request to you, once you will be having answers, please notify me. I will check tomorrow morning. +1

Comment: Thanks for the interest. I've found the answer. You probably wish to try it.

Comment: @ArupRakshit notifying you as you have requested. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to take an adventure through Enumerable, you could say this:

```
(a.map { |h| [:a, h] } + b.map { |h| [:b, h] })
    .group_by   { |_, h| h[:id]                      }
    .select     { |_, a| a.length == 2               }
    .inject({}) { |h, (n, v)| h.update(n => Hash[v]) }
```

And if you really want the keys to be strings, say `n.to_s => Hash[v]` instead of `n => Hash[v]`.

The logic works like this:

1. We need to know where everything comes from we decorate the little hashes with `:a` and `:b` symbols to track their origins.
2. Then add the decorated arrays together into one list so that...
3. [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) can group things into almost-the-final-format.
4. Then find the groups of size two since those groups contain the entries that appeared in both `a` and `b`. Groups of size one only appeared in one of `a` or `b` so we throw those away.
5. Then a little [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)ion to rearrange things into their final format. Note that the arrays we built in **(1)** just somehow happen to be in the format that [`Hash[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) is looking for.

If you wanted to do this in a `link` method then you'd need to say things like:

```
link :a => a, :b => b
```

so that the method will know what to call `a` and `b`. This hypothetical `link` method also easily generalizes to more arrays:

```
def link(input)
  input.map { |k, v| v.map { |h| [k, h] } }
       .inject(:+)
       .group_by   { |_, h| h[:id]                      }
       .select     { |_, a| a.length == input.length    }
       .inject({}) { |h, (n, v)| h.update(n => Hash[v]) }
end

link :a => [...], :b => [...], :c => [...]
```

Comment: Nice solution and good explanation.  Maybe `group_by {|_,h| h[:id]}` reads a bit better. (As you did that with `select` I expect you just missed that one).

Comment: Great solution! Despite on the fact that it is a bit longer than mine, I vote for this. It should be faster on big arrays and +1 for generalization. Thanks!

Comment: @Cary: You're right, `{|_,h| h[:id]}` is better with the `group_by`, I changed my mind about argument handling halfway through and missed it while reviewing. I guess that's another argument for code reviews, eh?

Comment: I'd like your opinion on a formatting question. In `link`, I might have lined up the left braces following `group_by` and `select` with `inject`'s left brace (by adding spaces, keeping the `.`'s lined up). I don't see that done by others, however. It seems to me that it makes it a tad easier to read.

Comment: @Cary: In real life I'd probably line everything up like in my last edit. I'm tempted to replace `|h, (n, v)|` with `|h, a|` just to make the pipes line up too but that's too OCD even for me :) I always put the `.`s at the beginning of the line (and line them up vertically) rather than at the end of the previous line: things on the left side get visually lost and those "I'm still chaining methods here" `.`s are too important to get lost. I might also replace the blocks with `lambda`s so that I could name the logic but the blocks are small enough that I don't that the names are needed here.

Comment: @Cary: We had a quick discussion about the `lambda`s just [last week](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21194055/479863) actually.

Comment: Aren't you forgetting `map` in `link`?  You could line up the right pipes if the balance grates.  `lambda`s?  Oh, yes, they're l-ike a m-ethod, b-oth d-emand a-rity.

Comment: @Cary: The block-less `inject` between the `map` and `group_by` would make the extra space look strange to me. That irritates me somewhat but not enough to switch the `inject`'s `:+` to a block. I do spend a fair bit of time worrying about these "minor formatting issues though and I will rewrite code to just to make it visually more appealing.

Comment: OK, I think we've beaten that to death.  Looks like it might be a good day for you to spend some time on the hill...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found the answer by myself. Here is a quite short line of code, which should do the trick:

```
 Hash[a.product(b)
       .select { |pair| pair[0][:id] == pair[1][:id] }
       .map { |pair| [pair[0][:id], { :a => pair[0], :b => pair[1] }] }]
```

The `product` method gives us all possible pairs, then we filter them by equal IDs of pair elements. And then we `map` pairs to the special form, which will produce a Hash we are looking for.

So `Hash[["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"]]` returns `{ "key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2" }`. And I use this to get the answer on my question.

Thanks.

P.S.: you can use `pair.first` instead of `pair[0]` and `pair.last` instead of `pair[1]` for better readability.

**UPDATE**
As Cary pointed out, it is better to replace `|pair|` with `|ha, hb|` to avoid these ugly indices:

```
Hash[a.product(b)
      .select { |ha, hb| ha[:id] == hb[:id] }
      .map { |ha, hb| [ha[:id], { :a => ha, :b => hb }] }]
```

Comment: This is quite a novel approach, Michael, +1.  As long as the arrays `a` and `b` are not huge it would work fine (as you are generating `a.size * b.size` pairs, then throwing out all but `min(a.size, b.size)`.  You may wish to replace the block argument `|pair|` with its 'disambigubated' equivalent, `|ha,hb|` so you don't need those ugly indices with `pair`.

Comment: Thanks for your remark, Cary. Yes, it looks like `product` is a weak point of this approach. However sometimes it may be useful. Useful tip about |ha, hb|!

Comment: Er, make that 'disambiguated'.  What an odd and, arguably, incorrect, use of that very odd word! (When I first saw it I thought it had been invented for that use, but no, it's right there in the OED, and predates the first computer.  And why isn't it just 'unambiguate'?)  I say 'arguably incorrect' because `|pair|` is not the least bit ambiguous, yet that's how the word is used.  Perhaps "constituent replacement", though longer, would be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that, for any two elements `h1` and `h2` of `a` (or of `b`), `h1[:id] != h2[:id]`.

I would do this:

```
def convert(arr) Hash[arr.map {|h| [h[:id], h]}] end
ah, bh = convert(a), convert(b)
c = ah.keys.each_with_object({}) {|k,h|h[k]={a: ah[k], b: bh[k]} if bh.key?(k)}
  # => {1=>{:a=>{:id=>1, :value=>1}, :b=>{:id=>1, :value=>2}},
  #     3=>{:a=>{:id=>3, :value=>3}, :b=>{:id=>3, :value=>4}}}
```

Note that:

```
ah = convert(a)
  # => {1=>{:id=>1, :value=>1}, 2=>{:id=>2, :value=>2}, 3=>{:id=>3, :value=>3}} 
bh = convert(b)
  # => {1=>{:id=>1, :value=>2}, 3=>{:id=>3, :value=>4}}
```

Here's a second approach.  I don't like it as well, but it represents a different way of looking at the problem.

```
def sort_by_id(a) a.sort_by {|h| h[:id]} end
c = Hash[*sort_by_id(a.select {|ha| b.find {|hb| hb[:id] == ha[:id]}})
      .zip(sort_by_id(b))
      .map {|ha,hb| [ha[:id], {a: ha, b: hb}]}
      .flatten]
```

Here's what's happening. The first step is to select only the elements `ha` of `a` for which there is an element `hb` of `b` for which `ha[:id] = hb[id]`.  Then we sort both (what's left of) `a` and `b` on `h[:id]`, `zip` them together and then make the hash `c`.

```
r1 = a.select {|ha| b.find {|hb| hb[:id] == ha[:id]}}
  # => [{:id=>1, :value=>1}, {:id=>3, :value=>3}] 
r2 = sort_by_id(r1)
  # => [{:id=>1, :value=>1}, {:id=>3, :value=>3}] 
r3 = sort_by_id(b)
  # => [{:id=>1, :value=>2}, {:id=>3, :value=>4}] 
r4 = r2.zip(r3)
  # => [[{:id=>1, :value=>1}, {:id=>1, :value=>2}],
  #     [{:id=>3, :value=>3}, {:id=>3, :value=>4}]] 
r5 = r4.map {|ha,hb| [ha[:id], {a: ha, b: hb}]}
  # => [[1, {:a=>{:id=>1, :value=>1}, :b=>{:id=>1, :value=>2}}],
  #     [3, {:a=>{:id=>3, :value=>3}, :b=>{:id=>3, :value=>4}}]]
r6 = r5.flatten
  # => [1, {:a=>{:id=>1, :value=>1}, :b=>{:id=>1, :value=>2}},
  #     3, {:a=>{:id=>3, :value=>3}, :b=>{:id=>3, :value=>4}}]
c = Hash[*r6]
  # => {1=>{:a=>{:id=>1, :value=>1}, :b=>{:id=>1, :value=>2}},
  #     3=>{:a=>{:id=>3, :value=>3}, :b=>{:id=>3, :value=>4}}}
```